# No right-click behavior under 12.04 for rabbitvcs

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, rabbitvcs

I've followed all the instructions for installing rabbitvcs and am running nautilus3 but do not get right-click svn options (I believe it worked under 10.10).

I should add that I'm running 12.04 under VMware Fusion. Any suggestions (I've searched the web but no luck).

Answer (score 0):

This is the same question as posted here [Using RabbitVCS on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198900/using-rabbitvcs-on-12-04) and my answer there should cover it: there is a conflict with UbuntuOne. Turn off all the automatic updates and RabitVCS works fine.