# Using RabbitVCS on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, rabbitvcs

I was evaluating  RabbitVCS as replacement  of RapidSVN to connect to my SVN repository on Ubuntu server.

This what I did on my 12.04

1. Opened the Ubuntu software centre
2. Searched for RabbitVCS-Core and RabbitVCS-nautilus. They were listed.
3. Installed both of them and they are successfull installed.

Then,

1. I used the dash home to see if I can find these programs.
2. Opened Home folder and right clicked on certain folders which was checked out using Rapid SVN. I could not find any options to use RabbitVCS in nautilus from here.
3. I restarted my machine and repeated both process again.

So How can I use RabbitVCS?

Am I seeing everything as it is expected or some thing weird?

Answer (score 3):

There is a conflict between RabbitVCS and Ubuntu One on Ubuntu 12.04 and RabbitVCS 15.2.

What finally worked for me after having had to live without RabbitVCS for months is the following:

1. Go to your Ubuntu One preferences in System Settings
2. Under "Settings" uncheck all "File Sync Setting"
3. Reboot (perhaps also just logout/in but I rebooted)

And now your RabbitVCS should work as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link and Please do let me know if it works !!

http://linuxdrops.com/install-rabbitvcs-svn-git-client-on-ubuntu-12-1012-0411-1011-04/